# Creating a generic button component in Blazor Server App

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to make a generic custom button component. I have the following codes:

**StyledButtton.razor (Child Component):**

```
    <div @onclick="@(() => onClick.InvokeAsync())" class="styled-btn" style="width: @Width; height: @Height;
                    border-radius: @BorderRadius;">
        <i class="@IconClass" style="font-size: @IconSize; color: @IconColor"></i>
    </div>

<style>
.styled-btn {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
}

    .styled-btn:hover {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .styled-btn:active {
        background-color: #ffd800;
        transition: all 0.1s ease;
    }
</style>
    
    
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Width { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Height { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string BorderRadius { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string IconColor { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string IconClass { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string IconSize { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback onClick { get; set; }
}
```

I use this button component in the following code:

**Equipment.razor (Parent Component):**

```
<TitleBar>
    <StyledButton BorderRadius="10px" Width="40px" Height="40px" IconColor="Black" IconSize="20px" IconClass="fa-solid fa-power-off" onclick="@ToggleSelectionMode"></StyledButton>
</StyledButton>
</TitleBar>

@code {
    public Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SelectionType SelectionType { get; set; } = Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SelectionType.Single;

    void ToggleSelectionMode()
    {
        if (SelectionType == Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SelectionType.Single)
        {
            SelectionType = Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SelectionType.Multiple;
        }
        else
        {
            SelectionType = Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SelectionType.Single;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a generic button that has `onClick` event handler and I can use it in different scenarios.
When I run the code, the following error is shown:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Action' to
> type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.PropertySetter.CallPropertySetter<TTarget,
> TValue>(Action<TTarget, TValue> setter, object target, object value)
>
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to set property 'onclick' on object
> of type 'ArtaNG_UI.Shared.SharedComponents.StyledButton'. The error
> was: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Action' to type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need some correction with Eventcallback and onclick event.

**ButtonBase.cs**

```
[Parameter] public string ButtonName {get;set;}

[Parameter] public EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> OnButtonClick {get;set;}
. 
.  
.  
and so on
```

**Button.razor**

```
<Button @onclick="@OnButtonClick"> @ButtonName </Button>
```

**AnotherComp.razor**

```
<Button ButtonName="Name" OnButtonClick="@(()=> Foo())"></Button>
```

You have to import your button component in _Import.razor file to access it globally.

I hope it will help you.